# A good strategy to find a Schur decomposition for a rank 1 matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, schur-decomposition

Let $u= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
-1\\
2 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $v= 
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
1\\
-1 
\end{pmatrix}$

$E=uv^T=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & -1\\ 
-2 & -1  &1 \\ 
4 & 2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
$

What would be a good strategy to find a Schur decomposition here ? I know that $u$ has eigenvalue $v^Tu=-1$ and the orthognal complement of $u$ must have eigenvalue $0$. I've been trying to do some gram smith but it all turns out very ugly, and I think I'm supposed to something smarter. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_1=(1,0,0)^T$. If $Q$ is a real orthogonal matrix $Q$ that has $u/\|u\|$ as its first column (i.e. $Qe_1=u$), then $Q^TEQ=(Q^Tu)(v^TQ)=e_1(v^TQ)$ is upper triangular (its first row is $v^TQ$ and the other two rows are zero). To construct $Q$, you may use a [Householder matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation):
$$
Q = I-\frac{2ww^T}{\|w\|^2},\ w=u-\|u\|e_1.
$$